# Sequelize hasOne/hasMany doesn't add FK

Tags: database, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

Why doesn't sequelize add foreign key if i do this (Everything is inside generator function):

```
User.hasOne(Request)
Request.belongsTo(User)

let usr = yield User.create({name: 'John'})
let req = yield Request.create({title: 'smthng'})

req.setUser(usr)
usr.setRequest(req)
```

After that request has foreign key to user, but user hasn't. Why?

**upd**
Also i can add multiple requests belonging to same user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered this question before on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746774/sequelize-one-to-one-relation/43748501#43748501). Basically the declarations from hasOne and hasMany they create the FK on the destination model. If you one that FK stays on the origin model on a relation 1:1, you have to use belongsTo, even sequelize docs recommend that [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#hasone).

> Even though it is called a HasOne association, for most 1:1 relations you usually want the BelongsTo association since BelongsTo will add the foreignKey on the source where hasOne will add on the target.

And for a relation between 1:N you have no other option than hasMany, and as I said, it create the FK on the destination model, because thats how it works a 1:N relation.

Comment: So, it's not possible to bind models to each other? I can get user requests only with `SELECT id FROM requests WHERE user_id = 1`?

Comment: Use belongsTo in the model you need the FK. If you need it on Request model, do this:  `Request.belongsTo(models.User, { as: 'user_id' });`